Installing apps (ie Reaper, librewolf) graphically
Ok so I'm trying again to install Reaper and other apps. I re-installed Ubuntu because things had gotten tangeled from my attempts. After all the Teminal copying and pasting i finally figured out that all I needed to do was to install Gnome software center or snap store - and I could find all the apps I wanted there! I found Reaper, Librewolf, Tidal HiFi and they installed without a problem!
But after my install Snap store wouldn't install 'cause it's integrated in app center, then I finally found Gnome software center that had the same icon. But to my dismay I could not find any of the aforementioned apps when doing a search!
So I assume i had some repository/PPA installed that let me find these apps/snaps. But I don't know which!
Now please, I want a Teminal free approach to this (or at least limited use). I would like to be able to say that using Ubuntu is easy to a friend who (like me) only has interacted with an operating system graphically. If this is not possible I think I know why Linux use is about 1%...
I am using the latest and updated version of Ubuntu 24 on a i7 16gig ram laptop.

Ubuntu is not the very user friendly distro it used to be. If you want a more user friendly distro where most things work out of the box, try Linux Mint instead (which has inbuilt flatpak support, and does not have multiple software store issue).

Thank you, I'll try it!

Try Flatpak instead.
Set up Flatpak and the Flatpak plugin for gnome software
sudo apt install flatpak gnome-software-plugin-flatpak

Add the flathub repo
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

Now, you will be able to find all these apps in GNOME Software.

Did not help, nor reaper, librewolf or Tidal HiFi appear.
